# Axapta: Edit form field values

Tags: forms, methods, axapta, x++

Using a 'clicked' override on a button, I'd like to modify values in an Axapta form.

I'm able to get data from the form field using:
    str strOld = Form_FieldName.valueStr();

I'm able to prepend text to the field using:
    Form_FieldName.pasteText(strNew);

I can't seem to find a .clear method or .value= method.  I'd like to replace the entire value in the field with new information.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the field is bound to a datasource, you have to modify the value in the datasource. If the field is bound to a variable, then modify the value of the variable itself. It is the easy an smart way to do it.

You can modify the value in the form control by using the **.text()** method. (The control have to be the **AutoDeclaration** property set to **Yes**). This is a setter-getter (parameter) type method used in AX. If no parameter is passed, it is user as getter (read). If you pass a value, this is a setter (write).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  When I use the .text(myValue) method, no exceptions are thrown, but nothing happens on the form either.  The field is databound.  Do you mind posting a bit of example code for modifying a value in the datasource?  Thanks

Comment: It whould be usefull if you post your own code with the exact problem you have. Datasource will be a table. You can make: Table.field = XX; element.redraw() //to refresh the form; Be carefull that this will modify the value in the database if you change the record (as usual in the standard)

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I'm just getting started in x++ after years of .NET.  It's been a bit of a painful transition.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Good luck with the learning. Syntax and philosophy is the same, just we have to fight with those tons of classes ;)